# How to turn off break line on jsp files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, editor

When I run format function (Shift+Ftrl+F) on jsf file, the text is divided into strange places. I want to turn off it or set more longer position to break line.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Web > HTML Files > Editor_ increase _Line width_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ***Window > Preferences: Web > HTML Files > Editor*** increase the ***Line width***.